# Http inbound gateway: Return HttpStatus

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I've a spring integration http inbound-gateway. I'd like to return specific http status codes in different cases of use. **Is there any way to specify the httpStatus in the response???**

I tried with a **excepion type router where each exception is a specific http status code**, but i don't know how to set the status code in the response and I don't find any help about it in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User a `<header-enricher/>` (or other means) to put the status in the `org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header of the reply message. (The header name is `"http_statusCode"` but using the constant is generally recommended).

The code can either be an `HttpStatus` object, or an Integer/String with the status code you want to return.

Please open a 'Documentation' JIRA issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT